# What's the difference between respond_to and respond_with in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I'm sending data to my controller I'm getting the following error

[image]

with the parameters

```
{"title"=>"some",
 "user_id"=>"2",
 "task"=>{"title"=>"some"}}
```

Why is that so? And what's the difference between respond_to and respond_with in Rails?

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    respond_with current_user.tasks.create(task_params)
  end

  private

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:id, :title, :due_date, :priority, :complete)
  end

end
```

When I'm using respond_to it says `Undefined method upcase for Task`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's saying it doesn't recognize the format of your response. Since `respond_with current_user.tasks.create(task_params)` will generate a `html` response.

In your routes.rb change

```
resources :tasks
```

to

```
resources :tasks, :defaults => {:format => "json"}
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20787998/respond-with-returns-unknown-format-rails) may help you

Comment: Sadly, to no avail. Still having the same trouble.

Comment: @BillyLogan I updated my answer, hopefully this second attempt works. I was able to get it to go on my local machine.

Comment: It turned out everything was a lot easier. I could just write `respond json:`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
def create
  respond_with(current_user.tasks.create(task_params), :location => tasks_url)
end
```